# codeigniter - use model result in controller to process another model query

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model

I am a bit stuck.

I have the below controller function. this works 100% with no issues.

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
{
          $data = array(
           'project' =>$this->input->post('project'),
           'millcoords' => $this->sales_model->get_mill_coords($this->input->post('mill')),
           'custcoords' => $this->sales_model->get_cust_coords($this->input->post('deliveryaddressid')),

          );
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
```

What I want to do is pass more model information to the view. my problem however is that I am needing the results of the previous model queries for my new model query. so I want to add to the array as follows:

```
   $data = array(
       'project' =>$this->input->post('project'),
       'millcoords' => $this->sales_model->get_mill_coords($this->input->post('mill')),
       'custcoords' => $this->sales_model->get_cust_coords($this->input->post('deliveryaddressid')),
       'customersinrange' =>  $this->sales_model->get_customers_in_range($millcoords,$custcoords),            
      );
```

So I want to pass two values to the model function get_customers_in_range. I want to pass the results of `millcoords` and the results of `custcoords`.

How can I achieve this so that the controller can use the results of a model query to execute a new model query?

Thanks as always,
Ryan

Comment: Instead of using result of one model query into another inside controller, you can use access the necessary model function call within the model function you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $millcoords = $this->sales_model->get_mill_coords($this->input->post('mill'));
$custcoords = $this->sales_model->get_cust_coords($this->input->post('deliveryaddressid'));
    $data = array(
           'project' =>$this->input->post('project'),
           'millcoords' => $millcoords,
           'custcoords' => $custcoords,
           'customersinrange' =>  $this->sales_model->get_customers_in_range($millcoords,$custcoords),            
          );
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
{
    $data                       = array();
    $data['project']            = $this->input->post('project', true);
    $data['millcoords']         = $this->sales_model->get_mill_coords( $this->input->post('mill') );
    $data['custcoords']         = $this->sales_model->get_cust_coords($this->input->post('deliveryaddressid'));
    $data['customersinrange']   = $this->sales_model->get_customers_in_range($data['millcoords'], $data['custcoords']);
    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$millcoords = $this->sales_model->get_mill_coords($this->input->post('mill');
$custcoords = $this->sales_model->get_cust_coords($this->input->post('deliveryaddressid');
$customersinrange = $this->sales_model->get_customers_in_range($millcoords,$custcoords);
    $data = array(
           'project' =>$this->input->post('project'),
           'millcoords' => $millcoords,
           'custcoords' => $custcoords,
           'customersinrange' => $customersinrange,            
          );


    $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
```